# Short connections in Lomé

Tags: short-connections, africa

I'm booking a ticket from New York to Abidjan and one of the affordable options involves taking Ethiopian's ET509 from Newark to Lomé (Togo) and then ASKY's KP52 on from Lomé to Abidjan (Senegal). The only issue is that the connection in Lomé is just 35 minutes.

Is a 35-minute connection in Lomé feasible? Is it possible that they hold the ASKY flight's departure for the ET509's passengers? I believe Ethiopian is the technical partner in the founding of ASKY, so perhaps they still have an operational role?

Comment: Is it all part of one ticket? If separate tickets there is NO WAY you will make your connection unless for some reason the ASKY flight gets delayed.

Comment: @SheikPaul Good point. Yes I can book it on one ticket through United. If I book through one of the OTAs that pops up on Momondo, that's also still all one ticket, right?

Comment: If they let you book it as one ticket, it means the connection meets the airport's and airlines' international-to-international minimum connecting time (MCT) requirement. Whether this means you have a high likelihood of actually making the connection is another story, but meeting the MCT at least means they believe the connection is theoretically possible.

Comment: They almost certainly won't hold a flight for a delayed (or even on-time) connecting passenger.

Comment: were you able to make the connection?

Comment: @Airride I pursued an alternative itinerary given the advice given in answers here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even travelling on a single ticket for the entire journey, you will never make that connection. The arrival time is almost certainly when the aircraft is expected to touch down, not when you're able to disembark. At minimum, that adds 20 minutes, or more, to when you enter the terminal.

[Aéroport Lomé](http://www.aeroport-lome.com/things_to_know_and_visa_togo.php#Convocations) notes that:

> The arriving passengers must count an average of 30 to 45 minutes to complete the formalities of police and customs and to retrieve their luggage.

Update: as @Crazydre has noted, there is airside transit so that you shouldn't have to go through customs and immigration for the onward flight. Your bags should be checked through to your destination if you book on the single ticket, but confirm that with your carrier. Booked separately, you would have to retrieve your bags and recheck them for the next flight.

Comment: You don't think they'd check the bags through to Abidjan? And would I actually have to clear customs?

Comment: @Shane They'll check it through, and you don't need to clear immigration

Comment: @Dorothy There is, it's stated in Timatic - it says whenever a country doesn't have it

Comment: @Dorothy At such a small airport 35 min should be enough unless the inbound flight is late or transfer security (if there is any) is packed

Comment: @Crazydre The inbound is a long-haul flight. It's pretty much 50/50 whether it's slightly late or slightly early.

Comment: Even if the bags are checked through, and even if the passenger manages to make the connection, there's a good chance that the bags won't make it. At that point, you're spending your first couple of days in what's probably an unfamiliar country trying to liase with baggage delivery companies. Avoid.